# PHP array to table with more than two columns

Tags: php, html, css

I have a little code that combines two arrays into a table with 2 columns. This works. But now I have a new array with values from `$file3`. I understand how to make a table with two columns, **but how can I add a third column with the content of `$file3`?**

```
<?php
    $file1 = "c:/presencetool/ramfile1.txt";
    $file2 = "c:/presencetool/ramfile2.txt";
    $file3 = "c:/presencetool/ramfile3.txt"; //new file
    if(file_exists($file1) && file_exists($file2))
    {
        $line1 = file($file1, FILE_IGNORE_NEW_LINES);
        $line2 = file($file2, FILE_IGNORE_NEW_LINES);
        $line3 = file($file3, FILE_IGNORE_NEW_LINES); //new array
        $combine = array_combine($line1, $line2); //I want to also combine $line3 here

        $html = '<table align="center">';
        $html .= '<tr><td width="350px";></td><td></td></tr>';
        $i = 1;
        foreach ($combine as $key => $value):
        $html .= '<tr class="'.$value.'">';
        $html .= '<td font-size:"90pt">'.$key.'</td>';
        $html .= '<td font-size:"90pt">'.$value.'</td>';
        //here something like $html .= '<td font-size:"90pt">'.$value2.'</td>';
        $html .= '</tr>';
        $i++;
        endforeach;
        $html .= '</table>';

        echo $html;
    }
```

In `$file1`, `$file2` and `$file3` are names, addresses and emails of some users.(one value per line)

Comment: You should create a 2D array rather than a key-value one.

Comment: @MrLister because a key-value array only works with 2 linked values right? I thought of that, but I was not quite sure how to create another type of array. Thank you! I will do some research about 2D arrays.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

if your array looks like this :

```
$line[] = ['name' => 'name1','email' => 'email@mail.com']; 
$line[] = ['name' => 'name2','email' => 'email2@mail.com']; 
$line[] = ['name' => 'name3','email' => 'email3@mail.com'];
```

Then try the below, hope will help you

```
$html = '<table align="center" border="1" width="50%">';
$html .= '<tr><th>Name</th><th>Email</th><th>Address</th></tr>';
for($i=0;$i<count($line1);$i++){
    $html .= '<tr class="'.$line1[$i].'">'; 
    $html .= '<td font-size:"90pt">'.$line1[$i].'</td>';
    $html .= '<td font-size:"90pt">'.$line2[$i].'</td>';
    $html .= '<td font-size:"90pt">'.$line3[$i].'</td>';
    $html .= '</tr>';
}
$html .= '</table>';

echo $html;
```

Comment: Actually no, $line1 is full of names, $line2 is full of addresses and $line 3 is full of email adresses

Comment: i have done some modification in the above code, kindly check the above result reflects your actual need @buttercup